# Проблема с запуском процесса, запускающего другие процессы от имени другого пользователя

Tags: c#, windows, процесс, консоль, планировщик-задач

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть программа, написанная на C#, запускающая и управляющая пользовательскими процессами (перехват потоков, лимиты по памяти и процессорному времени, преждевременное завершение процессов). Процессы запускаются от имени другого пользователя (тип открытия - runas, передаю логин и пароль пользователя).

Создана задача в планировщике задач, которая при запуске компьютера запускает написанную мой программу.

Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске моей программы с помощью планировщика задач, я не могу перехватывать потоки процесса, завершить работу программы и т.д. Ошибок никаких не возникает. Если запустить мою программу обычным путём (консольное приложение), всё работает отлично.

При этом, если моя программа запущена как процесс с помощью планировщика задач, и запускает пользовательские процессы от имени того же пользователя, ошибок нет, всё работает также хорошо, как и в случае со стандартным режимом запуска.

Решил обратиться к сообществу Stack Overflow так как решения этой проблемы в интернетах не нашёл. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

**UPD:** Если в планировщике задач выбрать пункт "Запускать только при входе пользователя в систему", программа работает без ошибок. В ином случае (пункт "Запускать всегда, не только при входе пользователя в систему", возникают вышеупомянутые ошибки.

P.S. Прошу прощения за неправильный перевод системного интерфейса, пользуюсь англоязычной версией ОС.

Comment: Задача запускается в планировщике от имени администратора?

Comment: @Andrei Да, от имени администратора.

Comment: Хм, нашёл вот ответ на один вопрос, интересно, правда ли это, или нет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106647/6057175 ?

Comment: Я вот об этом и хотел у вас уточнить в плане запуска через планировщик https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106679/8411541 Если вы этого пока еще не пробовали, то попробуйте, должно помочь

Comment: @andrei-s Перепроверил. Всегда запускал с наивысшими правами. Не помогает :( На всякий случай разрешил пользователю, от имени которого программа запускает дочерние процессы запускаться как batch job. Также не помогло... UAC отключён.

Comment: @Andrei а есть ещё какие-либо способы автозапуска программы при включении сервера? Пробовал с помощью Локальных политик, не работало... Этот вопрос очень важен. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А от имени какого пользователя происходит запуск программы в планировщике? Вы можете запускать от имени Администратора? Пробовали добавить пользователю от имени которого запускается программа дать права админа?

Comment: @Andrei был от Administrator, сейчас пробовал от System, аналогично не работает. Программа без прав админа не функционирует, так что юзаю только админские.