# Какие существуют способы автоматического запуска процесса в интерактивном режиме?

Tags: c#, процесс

**Предисловие:** *В своём предыдущем вопросе ([Проблема с запуском процесса, запускающего другие процессы от имени другого пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706177)) я не очень правильно выразился насчёт проблемы, которая меня настигла. Этот вопрос является продолжением этой темы.*

Если вкратце, я написал на C# программу, которая запускает другие программы от имени другого пользователя, причём эти программы запускаются не в интерактивном режиме (`new ProcessStartInfo().UseShellExecute = false`). Насколько я понял, моя программа корректно работает лишь в том случае, когда она запущена в интерактивном режиме, иначе программы она запускать не может.

Вопрос заключается в том, каковы есть способы автоматического запуска программ в интерактивном режиме, даже если пользователь, от имени которого мы запускаем эту интерактивную программу, не вошёл в систему.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию по этому поводу!

Comment: А что такое «интерактивный режим»? Почему вы связываете его с использованием `UseShellExecute`?

Comment: @VlaD не правильно выразился. Имеется ввиду user interactive mode (программа запускается в оболочке).